# JQuery countdown not working with datatables pagechange event

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-countdown

I'm working on of the coupon based website where i need to use countdown
script(http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) with datatables.

I encounter that page change event stops timer of the first page and also count is not working on other pages.

Here is my code for updating counter when page loads each time

```
$('#sample_2').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    alert("page changed");
    $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
        $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
            $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
        });
    }).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
        $(this).addClass("label label-sm label-danger");
        $(this).html('This offer has expired!');
    });
} );
```

HTML code

```
<tr>
    <td>f2 coupon</td>
    <td>
         <div data-countdown="2015-05-18 12:09:00" class="label label-sm label-success">20 days 15:04:54</div>
    </td>
    <td class="numeric">1</td>
    <td class="numeric">1</td>      
</tr>
```

Feel free to ask for more info if needed

Please advise.

-Niks

Comment: I suppose [data-countdown] are table columns. Is this right?

Comment: I have no idea what the problem might is but I would try different events if I had the same problem. Take a look here: https://datatables.net/reference/event/#Events . Maybe draw.dt ?

Comment: Thank for your quick response @Tsalikidis.Here i update question add some html for single row <tr>.you can try it with some variations in several rows and then change page with datatables pagination you will get the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [rowCallback event](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) of datatables plugin. Check the code snippet below.

```js
  // rowCallback is what you need
  function initDataTable() {
    $('table').DataTable({
      rowCallback: function(nRow) {
        /* This is your code */
        $(nRow).find('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
          var $this = $(this),
            finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
          $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
            $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
          });
        }).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
          $(this).addClass("label label-sm label-danger");
          $(this).html('This offer has expired!');
        });
      }
    });
  };

  // Ignore code below.. (I just needed something to populate this example table)
  $(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      $('table tbody').append('<tr>' +
        '<td> f2 coupon </td>' +
        '<td>' +
        '<div data-countdown="2015-05-18 12:09:00" class="label label-sm label-success">20 days 15:04:54</div> ' +
        ' </td>' +
        '<td class="numeric">1</td> ' +
        ' <td class = "numeric"> 1 </td>' +
        '</tr> ');
    }

    initDataTable();
  });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>f2 coupon</td>
          <td>
            <div data-countdown="2015-05-18 12:09:00" class="label label-sm label-success">20 days 15:04:54</div>
          </td>
          <td class="numeric">1</td>
          <td class="numeric">1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.0.4/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

</html>
```